# How to combine 2 tables in SAS like following data set?

Tags: sas

I have two data sets:

First:

```
Name    Bill
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       .
E       .
F       6
```

Second:

```
Name    Bill
D       4
E       5
```

I want to combine both into one table like so:

```
Name    Bill
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       4
E       5
F       6
```

I tried the merge statement, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share your attempt which failed?

Comment: Also, please format your data, I can't tell what's a variable name versus a variable value.

Comment: Just some hints:
1) you need to sort both dataset  by the mergekey, before merge.
2) since the variable not intended to be a mergekey is present on both datasets, you should rename it on one of the two datasets, for example you can rename Bill to Bill2 on second dataset, merge by name, and run a statement like: if bill2 ne . then bill=bill2;. Adding in option to dataset merge is an option.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use proc sql.

Let's set your sample data first:

```
DATA t1;
  INPUT Name $ Bill;
  DATALINES;
A 1
B 2
C 3
D .
E .
F 6
run;

DATA t2;
  INPUT Name $ Bill;
  DATALINES;
D 4
E 5
run;
```

I you simply want to replace missing values from the first table with corresponding ones in the second you can use left join and coalesce function.

```
procedure sql;
    create table newT as
    select 
        t1.Name
        ,coalesce(t1.Bill, t2.Bill) as Bill  
    from t1
    left join t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The MERGE statement will produce the answer you said you wanted.  Why do you think it did not work?

```
data want ;
  merge first second ;
  by name ;
run;
```